# app not running on simulator after facebook integration, shows duplicate symbols

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios-simulator

I have implemented login Facebook login functionality in my app.

**After that when i try to run the app in simulator it shows following error,**

Where when i run the app in **DEVICE** it works fine.

[image]

[image]

I have check all the scenarios here. not a single file is duplicated in project. and i didn't import any ".m" file.

how can i run my app in simulator with all implementation. Any help will be helpful.

Comment: @ChrisH : Thanks..i change the sdk version as suggested in the link which you provided, and now i can run my app in simulator

Answer (score 1):

Means that you have loaded same functions twice. As the issue disappear after removing  -ObjC from Other Linker Flags, this means that this option result that functions loads twice:

from Technical Q&A

> This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library
>   that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will
>   typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code
>   loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of
>   effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on
>   existing classes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html